# Are these 3 Matrices definable as products

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have 3 Matrices:

$$ A) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

$$ B) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

$$ C) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 2 \\
    -1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

And I am trying to figure out if these matrices are definable as a product.

I believe there are some requirements that are set for the dimensions that determine wether I can define these matrices as products.

From what I've come to assume so far, I can create a product of AB by multiplying the top row of A with the first column of B.

This leaves me with:

$$ AB) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    2 * 0 + 1 * (-1) + (-1) * 1 & 2 * 1 + 1 * 0 + (-1) * 1 \\
    0 * 0 + (-1) * (-1) + 1 * 1 & 0 * 1 + (-1) * 0 + 1 * 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

And if I am performing these steps correctly the product of AB would be:

$$ 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    -2 & 1 \\
    2 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Is this correct so far?

Also, are there any of these matrices that I cannot define as a product?

I'm wondering if I can create products from BA , AC , CA , BC & CB in the same way I did here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking which matrix products are *defined*. It all comes down to the dimensions of the matrices. If $X$ is a $x_1×x_2$ matrix and $Y$ is a $y_1×y_2$ matrix, $XY$ is only defined if $x_2=y_1$, and the result is a $x_1×y_2$ matrix.

Thus the products $AB,BA,AC,CB$ are defined; $CA,BC$ are not.

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response. I read in the book by Kenneth H. Rosen on Discrete Mathematics that "a product of two matrices is defined only when the number of columns in the first matrix equals the number of rows in the second matrix"

That, along with your reply, helped me get a clearer image of how to determine which products are defined or not.